# Utilizar función MOD de MongoDB para mostrar ciertos registros de fechas

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección donde donde sus registros tienen un campo de fecha y hora (el tipo de dato es ISODate), para una colección los registros están guardados a 15 minutos y para otra a 2 minutos. Como podría implementar el operador $mod para que me mostrará los registros a 30 o 45 minutos, para el caso de la primer colección o a 4 o 12 minutos para la segunda?

Les agradecería me pudieran dar algún ejemplo, a continuación les dejo unos registros a 15 minutos.

```
    /*1*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c81d29c00d51004440189b7"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2018-07-30T08:30:00.000Z"),
    "RECORD" : "276",
    "PTemp_C_Avg" : "7.261"
}

/*2*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c81d29c00d51004440189b8"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2018-07-30T08:45:00.000Z"),
    "RECORD" : "277",
    "PTemp_C_Avg" : "7.215"
}

/*3*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c81d29c00d51004440189b9"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2018-07-30T09:00:00.000Z"),
    "RECORD" : "278",
    "PTemp_C_Avg" : "7.218"
}

/*4*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c81d29c00d51004440189ba"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2018-07-30T09:15:00.000Z"),
    "RECORD" : "279",
    "PTemp_C_Avg" : "7.305"
}

/*5*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c81d29c00d51004440189bb"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2018-07-30T09:30:00.000Z"),
    "RECORD" : "280",
    "PTemp_C_Avg" : "7.499"
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado por tu cuenta hasta ahora?

Comment: Para consultar los datos a cada 30 minutos intente hacer una consulta como:     db.Registros_Sondas_Inspeccion2.find({
            "TIMESTAMP": {$gte: ISODate('2018-07-30T08:30:00.000Z')},
            "TIMESTAMP": {$lte: ISODate('2018-07-31T08:30:00.000Z')},
            $mod [15, 0]
        }).  Pero me devuelve unexpected token, la idea es que dado un rango de fechas yo pudiera mostrar los datos a cada cierto intervalo de tiempo, para este caso los intervalos son multiplos de 15. Es decir podria consultar datos a cada 30, 45, 60, 75, etc minutos.